# Remove negative from variable with shader function

Tags: shader

I have a variable which can be either negative or positive.

One way to make sure it is always positive is:

```
if (var < 0) var = -var;
```

However, there must be a shader function which can do this, I would think. I'm working with Cg, however if I know the terminology for what I want, I could look it up without reading through the entire reference manual.

Comment: Perhaps fract does this?

Comment: fract? Fract will return excatly what the name suggests, the fractional part of a number. Your question is a little misleading. If you want an absolute value of a signed integer, just say so and ask for a function that computes it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the absolute value

```
abs(var)
```